# Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password: yes Exception

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Error while installing MysqlServer in Windows 7:

At the end of the installation while mysql tries to finish up the security privilege update got the below exception.

> Error Nr: 1045
>   Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using passowrd:YES)
>
> If a personal firewall is running on your machine, please make sure you have opened the TCP port 3306 for connections. Otherwise no client application can connect to the server. After you have opened the port please press to apply the security settings.

Has any one gotten this before in Windows 7 and gotten it resolved?

Comment: Have you ever setup MySQL on this machine before?

Comment: Yes Jim, I have it installed and it was working fine. Suddenly only day it started throwing the above "access denied" when I tried to connect using mysql client. then I uninstalled and retired. but the installation itself was not going through. So, I uninstalled all the files and cleared the Programdata.. but that also did not helped.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Everyone, I got the issues resolved.  Here are the steps I followed.

1. Uninstalled MySQL server.
2. Deleted C:/programdata/mysql folder completely. If not, make sure mysql services is stopped and then delete it again.
3. delete the MySQL folder under program files after uninstalling it.
4. Install MySQL Administrator run command FLUSH PRIVILEGES.
5. Reinstall MySQL Server.
6. If you want a back up of your older tables you can copy the data present under C:/ProgramData other than mysql, test schemas and the copy it back into the folder after installation to retain the old data and restart the MySQL Services.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out before I could respond.  This is what I was going to have you do. Happened to me the other week.

Comment: You made me lose all my invoices. You could have placed a warning at step 2! Not everyone reads to the last step before they try solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure port 3306 is open.

1. Open the port using the Windows Firewall. `Start > Control Panels > Windows Firewall > Exceptions tab.`
2. Click the "Add Port" button: 
   Name: mysql 
   Port: 3306

Other than that you can edit `my.ini` file and change/check settings (and restart mysql after)

```
[mysqld] 
port = 3306 
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 
skip-locking 
key_buffer = 16M 
max_allowed_packet = 1M 
skip-grant-tables 
table_cache = 64 
sort_buffer_size = 512K 
net_buffer_length = 8K 
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
```